# Network image does not fit to the card

Tags: flutter, dart

Network image does not fit to the card.
I need a fix method that allows all the phone screens. In my case, the image looses it shape when phone size decreases.

```
Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
         0, 8, 0, 0),
         child: Container(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
         ),
         child: Image.network(product.productImage,height: 80),
        ),
       ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `fit` property

```
Image.network(product.productImage,height: 80, fit: BoxFit.cover),
```